# Expo Bare Workflow Android studio debugging Task :expo-permissions:compileDebugKotlin FAILED

Tags: android, react-native, expo, expo-permissions

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z52b1.png)

The problem seems to be comes from here :
import com.facebook.react.modules.core.PermissionAwareActivity

Errors:

> Task :expo-permissions:compileDebugKotlin FAILED
> Unresolved reference: PermissionAwareActivity

I got all theres errors while trying to debug my code in android studio.
Its a react native expo, after running expo-eject.
Anyone here seems to know whats this error about and how to fix this ?

My current buildscript

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 29
        targetSdkVersion = 29
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3")

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```